# Query to fetch service contracts in oracle apps

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone please help me have a query to fetch service contracts in oracle apps having covered Items only `(lse_id = 7)`?

I have built the query below, but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: You seem to have have missed off your query.